# How to execute jQuery code before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

How do I make my jQuery code execute before submit and before sending it to database?
I'm trying to take user input from checkbox, process it in jQuery and send this value to a hidden html field. When executing separately the code works as it should, console.log returns correct value, however when executed inside the project Django returns error that the value is empty ("") and jQuery alert added for debugging does not execute.

```
   <form id="cat-form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        <p>Imię:</p>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="cat_name" required>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <p>Question?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="f_low" name="friendliness" value="0" required>
        <label for="f_low">Answer 1</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" id="f_medium" name="friendliness" value="1">
        <label for="f_medium">Answer 2</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" id="f_high" name="friendliness" value="2">
        <label for="f_high">Answer 3</label>
    </ul>

    <ul><input type="hidden" id="friendliness_level" name="friendliness_level"></ul>

    <input type="submit"/>
    
    </form>
```

Script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
        $('#cat-form').submit(function() {
            // Take html user input into variables
            var friendliness = $("input[type=radio][name=friendliness]:checked").val();
            // populate hidden fields with variable values
            $('#friendliness_level').val(friendliness);
            console.log($('#friendliness_level').val())
        });
</script>
```

views.py

```
def cat_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cat = Cat()
        cat.friendliness_level = request.POST.get('friendliness_level')
        cat.save()

        return render(request, 'cats/cat_description.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'cats/cat_description.html')
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. The only valid children of `<ul>` is `<li>`. It's entirely possible that is the root of the problem as browsers have unpredictable behavior as to where the place invalid elements

Answer (score 0):

So the Javascript you're looking for is something like this;

```js
// Submit post on submit
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  // This stops it from submitting to the backend before you're ready
    console.log("form submitted!")
    // Do whatever you want here

    // Then submit the form
    $.ajax({
        url : "post_data/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { field : $('#form-field').val() }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Then you just need your view to respond with valid JSON.